# save and load numpy ndarray as txt file (keras weights)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

I want to use my keras model on different computers with different python versions

I don't want to use Pickle and numpy.savez because it causes problems in different environments

I start with that and it works fine

```
import json
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

def save_mod(model, name="my_model"):
    with open(name + '.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(model.to_json(), fp)

    # save weights
    model_weights = model.get_weights()
    return model_weights

def load_mod(model_weights_, name="my_model"):
    # load config
    with open(name + ".json", "r") as read_file:
        json_string = json.load(read_file)
    model_ = keras.models.model_from_json(json_string, custom_objects={})

    # load weights
    model_.set_weights(model_weights_)
    return model_

model = keras.models.load_model("segmentation.h5")
weights = save_mod(model)
loaded_model = load_mod(weights)
```

Then I try to save and load weights

```
np.savetxt('weights.txt', weights, fmt='%s')
loaded_weights = np.fromfile('weights.txt')

print(len(weights)) 
print(len(loaded_weights))

>> 112
>> 31013
```

I got 112 and 31013, method not working

```
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, np.column_stack(weights), fmt='%1.10f')
```

it says >> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 4 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

finally I did this

```
class EncodeNumpy(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


we = np.array(weights)
print(a.shape)
json_dump = json.dumps({'we': we}, cls=EncodeNumpy)

json_load = json.loads(json_dump)
a_restored = np.asarray(json_load["we"])
print(a_restored.shape)

model.set_weights(a_restored)
```

it gave me (112,) and (112,) shaped arrays

but model.set_weights(a_restored) returns

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

is caused by numpy failing to convert the inner lists into ndarrays due to size mismatch.

See the example: lists having the same size

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [1, 2, 3]])
```

vs. lists having a different size

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]])
# array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

This is not what you want anyway. The correct way in this case is to turn each inner list into ndarray separately and place them into a list instead of ndarray.

For example, you can do something like:

```
a_restored = [np.asarray(el) for el in json_load["we"]]
```

You should be able to load the weights now.

```
json_load = json.loads(json_dump)
a_restored = [np.asarray(el) for el in json_load["we"]]
model.set_weights(a_restored)
```